# Pygame: move a spinning image around the edge of the window

Tags: python, pygame

I have an assignment that asks me to do the following:

Use Google's advanced image search to find a reasonably-sized image of a ball that is free to reuse and that includes transparency.  Modify the sample code so that your ball slides back and forth across the bottom of the screen.  It should take 2 seconds for the ball to go from the left side to the right.
Improve your animation for question 5 so that the ball rotates, accurately, as if it were rolling back and forth.
Modify your animation for question 6 so that the ball travels counterclockwise around the edge of the screen

I am at the last part. Trying to modify the animation for question 6 to do this: (1:24)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEiLc_UFNLI&feature=c4-overview&list=UUpbgjjXBL3hdTKDZ0gZvdWg

I'm stumped pretty bad. I just can't seem to understand how I will get the ball to slowly move from one point to another. The ball is an image. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work.

```
"""Some simple skeleton code for a pygame game/animation

This skeleton sets up a basic 800x600 window, an event loop, and a
redraw timer to redraw at 30 frames per second.
"""
from __future__ import division
import math
import sys
import pygame


class MyGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize a new game"""
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
        pygame.init()

        # set up a 640 x 480 window
        self.width = 800
    self.height = 600
    self.img = pygame.image.load('ball.png')
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.angle = 0
    self.rotate_right=True
    self.first = True
    #0: Move bottomleft to bottomright 1: Move from bottomright to topright 2:Move from topright to topleft 3:Move from topleft to bottomleft
    self.mode = 0
    # use a black background
    self.bg_color = 0, 0, 0

    # Setup a timer to refresh the display FPS times per second
    self.FPS = 30
    self.REFRESH = pygame.USEREVENT+1
    pygame.time.set_timer(self.REFRESH, 1000//self.FPS)


def get_mode(self):
    rect = self.img.get_rect()

    if self.first == True:
        self.first = False 
        return

    if (self.x, self.y) == (0, self.height - rect.height):
        #Our starting point, bottom left
        self.mode = 0
    elif (self.x, self.y) == (self.width-rect.width, self.height-rect.height):
        #Bottom right
        self.mode = 1
    elif (self.x, self.y) == (self.width-rect.width, 0):
        #Top Right
        self.mode = 2
    elif (self.x, self.y) == (0,0):
        #Top Left
        self.mode = 3

def get_target(self):
    rect = self.img.get_rect()

    if self.mode == 0:
        targetPosition = (0, self.height - rect.height)

    elif self.mode == 1:
        targetPosition = (self.width-rect.width, self.height-rect.height)

    elif self.mode == 2:
        targetPosition = (self.width-rect.width, 0)

    elif self.mode == 3:
        targetPosition = (0,0)

    return targetPosition

def get_angle(self):
    if self.angle == 360:
        self.rotate_right = False
    elif self.angle == 0:
        self.rotate_right = True

    if self.rotate_right == True:
        self.angle+=12
    else:
        self.angle-=12

def run(self):
    """Loop forever processing events"""
    running = True
    while running:
        event = pygame.event.wait()

        # player is asking to quit
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # time to draw a new frame
        elif event.type == self.REFRESH:
            self.draw()

        else:
            pass # an event type we don't handle            

def draw(self):
    """Update the display"""
    # everything we draw now is to a buffer that is not displayed
    self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)

    #Draw img
    rect = self.img.get_rect()

    #Note: this can be made dynamic, but right now since this is typically a poor structure, we will use static values.
    #80 is the padding, so it hits right before.

    #0,0 : top left
    #self.width-rect.width, 0  : top right
    #0, self.height-rect.height : bottom left  
    #self.width-rect.width, self.height-rect.height : bottom right

    targetPosition = ()

    #img = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.angle)
    img = self.img

    self.get_angle()
    self.get_mode()

    targetPosition = self.get_target()

    print targetPosition
    print self.x, self.y
    if self.x < targetPosition[0]:
        self.x+= targetPosition[0]-self.x//self.FPS

    elif self.x > targetPosition[0]:
        self.x-= targetPosition[0]+self.x//self.FPS

    if self.y < targetPosition[1]:
        print "s"
        self.y+= targetPosition[1]-self.y//self.FPS

    elif self.y > targetPosition[1]:
        self.y-= targetPosition[1]+self.y//self.FPS 


    rect = rect.move(self.x, self.y)

    self.screen.blit(img, rect)

    # flip buffers so that everything we have drawn gets displayed
    pygame.display.flip()


MyGame().run()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Hello! What do you mean by "it doesn't work?" It looks like you've got the code to move the ball -- what is the code supposed to do, and what does it currently do?

Comment: Well it is suppose to start at the bottom left, slowly move to the bottom right, then to the top right then top left and repeat. Currently it doesn't even move. I also posted a youtube link that explains what it has to do.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your ball is starting at `(0,0)` (top left) with a target of `(0,550)` (bottom left), discovers that it's at a lower `y` than its target, and promptly proceeds to increment its position by

`targetPosition[1] - (self.y // self.FPS)`

which is of course equal to 550, so it immediately snaps to the bottom of the screen.

Then during the next draw loop, `get_mode()` comes along and says 'okay, I'm at `(0, 550)`, so I'll go ahead and set the mode to `0`'. Then `get_target()` comes along and says 'okay, I'm in mode `0`, let's go over to `(0, 550)`.

And then this happens again during the next draw loop, and the next, and the next ... So of course your ball doesn't go anywhere.

You'll need to do a couple of things to fix your example:

- Fix your target positions in `get_target()`. Right now they're targeting the same points where the transitions that trigger those modes happen, so your ball won't go anywhere.
- Consider your velocity statements more carefully: right now they'll behave somewhat strangely. One way to do this properly is to determine `(dx, dy)` - that is, the absolute vector from you to your destination - and then normalize this vector such that it points in the same direction but has a magnitude equal to your desired speed. This approach will work for any target position you want.

To elaborate on the second point:

Suppose we're at `(x, y)` and we're trying to get to `(target_x, target_y)`.

Let `dx = target_x - x, dy = target_y - y`. This should be uncontroversial: we're just taking the difference.

Then we remember the Pythagorean theorem: given a right triangle with sides `a, b, c` and hypotenuse `c`, we recall that `len(c)**2 == len(a)**2 + len(b)**2`. It's the same thing with vectors: the length of a vector `(x, y)` is the hypotenuse of a right triangle with side lengths `x` and `y`. You can draw this on a piece of paper if you want to prove this to yourself.

Given that, we can find the length of `(dx, dy)`: it's just `L(dx, dy) = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)`. This lends itself to a curious observation: if we multiply both `dx` and `dy` by a scalar `k`, we also multiply the length by `k`, since `sqrt(dx*k*dx*k + dy*k*dy*k) == sqrt(k*k*(dx*dx + dy*dy)) == k*sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)`.

It follows that we can find a vector parallel to `(dx, dy)`, but of length 1, by dividing both `dx` and `dy` by `L(dx, dy)`. Precompute `L` to avoid some potential issues. Multiply this new vector by whatever you want your speed to be: this is your desired velocity.

Comment: This is the part where I get stuck - the math part. I'm unsure how to do the vector stuff. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well because I still am having trouble understanding it, I sort of accomplished it. Only issue I'm having now is that when I try rotating it, it starts shaking.